# How can I add a css element change to an onlick event in this jquery lib?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I've got this awesome slideshow library working just fine on my site (yoinked from codrops), but since I'm shifting between different pieces of information, I want to really call out the difference by adding a CSS change so that the background color matches the color of the content in the slide. Now, this is a library, so i figure I need to add the $('body').css call into it, and not my html doc. I'm including the code below, with a note marking where I think it's supposed to go. I'm jsut not sure what the exact phrasing would be since I've never worked inside a lib before. Any suggestions would be welcome!

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

// global
var Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

$.CBPFWSlider = function( options, element ) {
    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );
};

// the options
$.CBPFWSlider.defaults = {
    // default transition speed (ms)
    speed : 500,
    // default transition easing
    easing : 'ease'
};

$.CBPFWSlider.prototype = {
    _init : function( options ) {
        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.CBPFWSlider.defaults, options );
        // cache some elements and initialize some variables
        this._config();
        // initialize/bind the events
        this._initEvents();
    },
    _config : function() {

        // the list of items
        this.$list = this.$el.children( 'ul' );
        // the items (li elements)
        this.$items = this.$list.children( 'li' );
        // total number of items
        this.itemsCount = this.$items.length;
        // support for CSS Transitions & transforms
        this.support = Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms;
        this.support3d = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
        // transition end event name and transform name
        var transProperties = {
            'WebkitTransition' : { transitionEndEvent : 'webkitTransitionEnd', tranformName : '-webkit-transform' },
            'MozTransition' : { transitionEndEvent : 'transitionend', tranformName : '-moz-transform' },
            'OTransition' : { transitionEndEvent : 'oTransitionEnd', tranformName : '-o-transform' },
            'msTransition' : { transitionEndEvent : 'MSTransitionEnd', tranformName : '-ms-transform' },
            'transition' : { transitionEndEvent : 'transitionend', tranformName : 'transform' }
        };
        if( this.support ) {
            this.transEndEventName = transProperties[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ].transitionEndEvent + '.cbpFWSlider';
            this.transformName = transProperties[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ].tranformName;
        }
        // current and old item´s index
        this.current = 0;
        this.old = 0;
        // check if the list is currently moving
        this.isAnimating = false;
        // the list (ul) will have a width of 100% x itemsCount
        this.$list.css( 'width', 100 * this.itemsCount + '%' );
        // apply the transition
        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.css( 'transition', this.transformName + ' ' + this.options.speed + 'ms ' + this.options.easing );
        }
        // each item will have a width of 100 / itemsCount
        this.$items.css( 'width', 100 / this.itemsCount + '%' );
        // add navigation arrows and the navigation dots if there is more than 1 item
        if( this.itemsCount > 1 ) {

            // add navigation arrows (the previous arrow is not shown initially):
            this.$navPrev = $( '<span class="cbp-fwprev"><</span>' ).hide();
            this.$navNext = $( '<span class="cbp-fwnext">></span>' );
            $( '<nav/>' ).append( this.$navPrev, this.$navNext ).appendTo( this.$el );
            // add navigation dots
            var dots = '';
            for( var i = 0; i < this.itemsCount; ++i ) {
                // current dot will have the class cbp-fwcurrent
                var dot = i === this.current ? '<span class="cbp-fwcurrent"></span>' : '<span></span>';
                dots += dot;
            }
            var navDots = $( '<div class="cbp-fwdots"/>' ).append( dots ).appendTo( this.$el );
            this.$navDots = navDots.children( 'span' );

        }

    },
    _initEvents : function() {

        var self = this;
        if( this.itemsCount > 1 ) {
            this.$navPrev.on( 'click.cbpFWSlider', $.proxy( this._navigate, this, 'previous' ) );
            this.$navNext.on( 'click.cbpFWSlider', $.proxy( this._navigate, this, 'next' ) );
            this.$navDots.on( 'click.cbpFWSlider', function() { self._jump( $( this ).index() ); } );
        }

    },
    _navigate : function( direction ) {

        // do nothing if the list is currently moving
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }

        this.isAnimating = true;
        // update old and current values
        this.old = this.current;
        if( direction === 'next' && this.current < this.itemsCount - 1 ) {
            ++this.current;
//***I think maybe it goes here?!?
        }
        else if( direction === 'previous' && this.current > 0 ) {
            --this.current;
//***I think maybe it goes here?!?
        }
        // slide
        this._slide();

    },
    _slide : function() {

        // check which navigation arrows should be shown
        this._toggleNavControls();
        // translate value
        var translateVal = -1 * this.current * 100 / this.itemsCount;
        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.css( 'transform', this.support3d ? 'translate3d(' + translateVal + '%,0,0)' : 'translate(' + translateVal + '%)' );
        }
        else {
            this.$list.css( 'margin-left', -1 * this.current * 100 + '%' ); 
        }

        var transitionendfn = $.proxy( function() {
            this.isAnimating = false;
        }, this );

        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.on( this.transEndEventName, $.proxy( transitionendfn, this ) );
        }
        else {
            transitionendfn.call();
        }

    },
    _toggleNavControls : function() {

        // if the current item is the first one in the list, the left arrow is not shown
        // if the current item is the last one in the list, the right arrow is not shown
        switch( this.current ) {
            case 0 : this.$navNext.show(); this.$navPrev.hide(); break;
            case this.itemsCount - 1 : this.$navNext.hide(); this.$navPrev.show(); break;
            default : this.$navNext.show(); this.$navPrev.show(); break;
        }
        // highlight navigation dot
        this.$navDots.eq( this.old ).removeClass( 'cbp-fwcurrent' ).end().eq( this.current ).addClass( 'cbp-fwcurrent' );

    },
    _jump : function( position ) {

        // do nothing if clicking on the current dot, or if the list is currently moving
        if( position === this.current || this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;
        // update old and current values
        this.old = this.current;
        this.current = position;
        // slide
        this._slide();

    },
    destroy : function() {

        if( this.itemsCount > 1 ) {
            this.$navPrev.parent().remove();
            this.$navDots.parent().remove();
        }
        this.$list.css( 'width', 'auto' );
        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.css( 'transition', 'none' );
        }
        this.$items.css( 'width', 'auto' );

    }
};

var logError = function( message ) {
    if ( window.console ) {
        window.console.error( message );
    }
};

$.fn.cbpFWSlider = function( options ) {
    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
        this.each(function() {
            var instance = $.data( this, 'cbpFWSlider' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on cbpFWSlider prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }
            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for cbpFWSlider instance" );
                return;
            }
            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
        });
    } 
    else {
        this.each(function() {  
            var instance = $.data( this, 'cbpFWSlider' );
            if ( instance ) {
                instance._init();
            }
            else {
                instance = $.data( this, 'cbpFWSlider', new $.CBPFWSlider( options, this ) );
            }
        });
    }
    return this;
};

} )( jQuery, window );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question with a little digging.

```
_navigate : function( direction ) {

        // do nothing if the list is currently moving
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }

        this.isAnimating = true;
        // update old and current values
        this.old = this.current;
        if( direction === 'next' && this.current < this.itemsCount - 1 ) {
            ++this.current;

        }
        else if( direction === 'previous' && this.current > 0 ) {
            --this.current;
        }
        console.log(this.current);
        if(this.current == 0)
        {
            $('body').css('background', '#FF6A00');
        }else if(this.current == 1)
        {
            $('body').css('background', '#595C5A');
        }else if(this.current == 2)
        {
            $('body').css('background', '#000000');
        }
        // slide                                                                                        //AROUND HERE?
        this._slide();

    },
```